# How to get undefined amount of SQL queries which depend on each other to perform well

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysqli

I build a logic to generate random sentences. For this I have a database table with ~ 1.000.000 entires containing trigrams.

The current logic is:

1. get initial word
2. get next word based on first word
3. continue until entry matches end flag

In php it looks something like this

```
while($i < 30 && $last['three'] != '[end]') {
  $last = getDBentry($mysqli, $last);
  if($last['three'] != '[end]') {
    $string .= ' ' . $last['three'];
  }
  $i++;
}
```

I limited it to max. 30 but even with only like 10 words this takes about 15 seconds. Is there a best practice or good way to perform better on this amount of data?

EDIT

```
function getDBentry () {
...
$key = $last['two'].$last['three'];

if($single) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM trigrams WHERE gramkey = '$key'";
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM trigrams WHERE gramkey = '$key' AND amount > 1";
}

$matches = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) { 
    if($result->num_rows === 0 && $single) {
        die('error no result');
    }

    if($result->num_rows === 0) {
        return getDBentry($mysqli, $last, true);
    }

    while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){ 
        array_push($matches, array('one' => $obj->one, 'two'=>$obj->two, 'three'=>$obj->three, 'amount'=>$obj->amount, 'gramkey'=>$obj->gramkey));
    } 
} else {
    die('error');
}

...
```

I took the part which is important regarding the topic

Table structure is

id, gramkey, one, two, three, amount - whereby one two three are single words and the gramkey consists of one and two parsed into a single string to make it easily accessible

Comment: Please show you table structure, sample data, and output from your current code, along with the SQL the `getDBentry()` is performing (or the full function definition if its simple enough)

Comment: Are you calling the DB each time you run through the loop?

Comment: Yes I'm calling the db each time I run through the loop, i ll add the function in a second

Comment: Why not add the limit to the query? I'm fairly certain that it would save you a lot of time.

Comment: Do you have any indexes?

Comment: If I add limits to the query I'm not able to make the result "random". Otherwise I could use sql random (could I ?) But I'm not sure this will improve performance then

Comment: @AlexBlex no I do not have indexes - I'm a little bit of a newby regarding databases - which col would I need to index?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: @AlexBlex feel free to add this as answer - it now just works in milliseconds :)

Comment: @FrankProvost, you learnt it yourself and can answer your own question.

Comment: Please provide the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by AlexBlex in the comments the solution can be fonud in the mysql docs.

By adding an index for the col gramkeys the performance-increase was absolutly crazy. From like 15 secs to 0.1 sec.

EDIT: SHOW CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `trigrams` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`gramkey` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`one` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`two` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`three` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `gramkey` (`gramkey`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1055131 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```